# EJB 3.1 Binding does not work on Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

I want to call a local Stateless-EJB from on ejb project from another singleton-EJB in another ejb-project. Both EJB-Projects are in the same ear file. The Application Server is a WebSphere Application Server 8.0.0.1.

First EJB 3.1-Project (PersistenceEJB.jar):

Interface

```
@Local
public interface TaskInfoDao extends DaoTemplate<TaskInfo> {
    public int deleteAll();
}
```

The Stateless Bean:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class TaskInfoDaoImpl implements TaskInfoDao {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyDatasource")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public int deleteAll() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM TaskInfo t");
        int count = query.executeUpdate();
        return count;
    }

}
```

The ejb-jar.xml and ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml are empty.

Second EJB 3.1-Project (SchedulerEJB.jar):

Singleton:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartUpBean {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StartUpBean.class
            .getName());

    @EJB
    private TaskInfoDao taskInfoDao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStart() {
        LOGGER.info("DELETED: " + taskInfoDao.deleteAll());
   }
}
```

META-INF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: PersistenceEJB.jar
```

My "ejb-jar.xml" and "ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml" are empty (in both projects).

ear-File:
-META-INF
 |-application.xml
 |-ibm-application-ext.xml
 |-ibm-applcaiton-bnd.xml
 |-MANIFEST.MF
-PersistenceEJB.jar
-SchedulerEJB.jar

application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_ID" version="6"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">
    <description>...</description>
    <display-name>SchedulerAppEAR</display-name>
    <module id="Module_1392974920540">
        <ejb>SchedulerEJB.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module id="Module_1392975196627">
        <ejb>PersistenceEJB.jar</ejb>
    </module>
</application>
```

The other files in ear META-INF are empty.

On JVM-Startup I get the following Exception:

```
[21.02.14 13:15:16:760 CET] 0000003a EJBApplicatio E   CNTR0190E: The StartUpBean startup singleton session bean in the SchedulerEJB.jar module failed initialization with exception:
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: An error occurred during initialization of singleton session bean SchedulerAppEAR#SchedulerEJB.jar#StartUpBean, resulting in the discarding of the singleton instance.; nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The scheduler.StartUpBean/taskInfoDao EJB reference in the StartUpBean component in the SchedulerEJB.jar module of the SchedulerAppEAR application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface persistence.dao.TaskInfoDao not present in application SchedulerAppEAR
javax.ejb.EJBException: The scheduler.StartUpBean/taskInfoDao EJB reference in the StartUpBean component in the SchedulerEJB.jar module of the SchedulerAppEAR application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface persistence.dao.TaskInfoDao not present in application SchedulerAppEAR
com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface persistence.dao.TaskInfoDao not present in application SchedulerAppEAR
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.getHomeByInterface(HomeOfHomes.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(EJBLinkObjectFactory.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(EJBLinkObjectFactory.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.processor.EJBInjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(EJBInjectionBinding.java:1181)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectableObject(InjectionBinding.java:1003)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTarget.inject(InjectionTarget.java:198)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.inject(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:924)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.SingletonBeanO.initialize(SingletonBeanO.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createSingletonBeanO(EJSHome.java:4985)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.createStartupBeans(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:971)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.startedModule(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:695)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.stateChanged(EJBContainerImpl.java:5501)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1083)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1352)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:243)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:744)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1332)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2128)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5315)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5531)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1224)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.ready(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650)
javax.ejb.EJBException: The scheduler.StartUpBean/taskInfoDao EJB reference in the StartUpBean component in the SchedulerEJB.jar module of the SchedulerAppEAR application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface persistence.dao.TaskInfoDao not present in application SchedulerAppEAR
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface persistence.dao.TaskInfoDao not present in application SchedulerAppEAR
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.getHomeByInterface(HomeOfHomes.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(EJBLinkObjectFactory.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(EJBLinkObjectFactory.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.processor.EJBInjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(EJBInjectionBinding.java:1181)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectableObject(InjectionBinding.java:1003)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTarget.inject(InjectionTarget.java:198)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.inject(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:924)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.SingletonBeanO.initialize(SingletonBeanO.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createSingletonBeanO(EJSHome.java:4985)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.createStartupBeans(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:971)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.startedModule(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:695)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.stateChanged(EJBContainerImpl.java:5501)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1083)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1352)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:243)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:744)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1332)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2128)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5315)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5531)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1224)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.ready(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650)
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: An error occurred during initialization of singleton session bean SchedulerAppEAR#SchedulerEJB.jar#StartUpBean, resulting in the discarding of the singleton instance.; nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The scheduler.StartUpBean/taskInfoDao EJB reference in the StartUpBean component in the SchedulerEJB.jar module of the SchedulerAppEAR application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface persistence.dao.TaskInfoDao not present in application SchedulerAppEAR
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: The scheduler.StartUpBean/taskInfoDao EJB reference in the StartUpBean component in the SchedulerEJB.jar module of the SchedulerAppEAR application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface persistence.dao.TaskInfoDao not present in application SchedulerAppEAR
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface persistence.dao.TaskInfoDao not present in application SchedulerAppEAR
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.getHomeByInterface(HomeOfHomes.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(EJBLinkObjectFactory.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(EJBLinkObjectFactory.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.processor.EJBInjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(EJBInjectionBinding.java:1181)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectableObject(InjectionBinding.java:1003)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTarget.inject(InjectionTarget.java:198)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.inject(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:924)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.SingletonBeanO.initialize(SingletonBeanO.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createSingletonBeanO(EJSHome.java:4985)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.createStartupBeans(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:971)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.startedModule(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:695)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.stateChanged(EJBContainerImpl.java:5501)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1083)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1352)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:243)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:744)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1332)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2128)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5315)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5531)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1224)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.ready(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650)
```

So whats wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
When I use ibm.websphere.startupservice interface for my startupbean the bean injection works fine. To use this interface I removed the @Startup + @ Singleton interface.
Also I changed my class as:

```
public class StartUpBean implements javax.ejb.SessionBean {
 ...
 public boolean start() throws FileNotFoundException {
   ...
   return true;
 }
}
```

And my ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>SchedulerEJB</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session id="StartUp">
            <ejb-name>StartUp</ejb-name>
            <home>com.ibm.websphere.startupservice.AppStartUpHome</home>
            <remote>com.ibm.websphere.startupservice.AppStartUp</remote>
            <ejb-class>ejb.StartUpBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
        </session>
        </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

But I dont like this way because it depends on the application server I use...

Comment: That class-path line in the manifest.mf is weird; I would remove that. Web/enterprise application classpaths are managed by the container, don't do things that can interfere with that.

Comment: I removed this line, but I get the same Exception...

Comment: Good, that is ruled out then. So, the error is "there is no EJB with this name deployed"; I am going to assume the container is not lying. So is the EJB/interface present? Are the class files physically in the right module and in the right place in the deployment area?

Comment: Yes both modules are located in ear file in installedApps. Also the classes are available in *.jar.

Comment: Also in the application.xml?

Comment: Yes! All config XML look fine

Comment: Do I need do add some config in ejb-jar.xml or ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml?

Comment: No you don't, unless Websphere has some specific rules to the ibm config file; can't say anything about that, I don't know the container. Sorry to say, I'm at this point out of ideas. Try removing those two files though.

Comment: Gimby may be right in assuming Container is not lying. When you EAR is deployed, the container should automatically inspect your EAR and find your EJB-JAR file and deploy. Looks like that is what failing. You may want to post your EAR contents and specifically your EJB JAR with deployment descriptors(ejb-jar.xml and ibm-ejb-jar.xml) to understand the issue better.

Comment: I edited my question: added ear content. The EJB Deploymentdescriptors are empty.

Comment: Check out this bug report from IBM: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM62774 . There is a JVM property that you can set as a fix, but it might not be available in 8.0.0.1. That property has helped me before with startup beans and injection.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `TaskInfoDaoImpl` bean is contained in a different module than the one containing the client class, try using the portable JNDI name in the `@EJB` annotation as follows:

```
@EJB(name="java:app/PersistenceEJB/TaskInfoDaoImpl")
private TaskInfoDao taskInfoDao;
```

More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html).

Comment: From server log I found out that the container first bind the scheduler (singleton). At this time the classes of persistence is not bound to server. But the container tries to inject the stateless bean in the singleton. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? The annotatin should drive the AS to proper loading order.

Comment: Same behavior... The container binds the singleton ejb first and throws the exception...

Comment: Sounds strange, it could be a Websphere issue, another option would be  removing the EJB annotation and creating the bean using JNDI lookup in the `PostConstruct` method in your singleton (annotate it with `@Startup`), look at the link I suggested in my answer for more details.